# WindowSize attribute missing from deployer-conf.xml in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: publishing, web8.5, configuration, deployer

In Tridion 2013 SP1, there was an attribute called `WindowSize` in the `cd_deployer_conf.xml` file.
If you set the value of the `WindowSize` attribute to 1 and publish a large number of Pages or Components, only one Publish Transaction will be `waiting for deployment`, all others will be `throttled`. In addition, only one transport package is placed in the incoming directory on the Content Delivery side.

In Web 8.5, the `WindowSize` attribute has been removed from the `deployer_conf.xml` file. When publishing a large number of pages and components, a large number of (hundreds of) publish transactions will be "waiting for deployment" and a large number of transport packages will be placed in the incoming directory on the Content Delivery side. As a result, queries to obtain publish status are executed in large quantities, the load on the database suddenly increases, the deployment process is further delayed, eventually the publishing process is stuck.

Why was the `WindowSize` attribute deleted in Web 8.5?

And how do you finally solve the publish stuck by causing many publish transactions in the "waiting for deployment" state?

We found troubleshooting content in the SDL Web 8.5 [manual](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-6734091A-28AE-45FE-A66C-B75E35A4B492&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-278E2AB0-0B4F-4AC9-B65F-E983C7BAFA90.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-6734091A-28AE-45FE-A66C-B75E35A4B492), but it did not help us.

Answer (score 1):

**Content Manager**

Increase polling in the transport configuration file, (CMS)\SDL Web\config\cd_transport_conf.xml

For instance, this is the default entry and the numbers may need to be raised via a tuning exercise.

```
<!-- Specifies the polling attempts and timeout in minutes and interval between polls in milliseconds -->
<Polling MaxAttempts="900" Timeout="15" Interval="5000"/>
```

Restart the transport service for this change to take effect.

**Content Delivery**

In the deployer service application.properties file to increase the maximum size permitted for uploaded/allowed for files requests according to your maximum package size requirements

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1000Mb

spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=1000Mb
```

clean you incoming queue folder, restart deployer for these changes to take effect and publish again

Comment: Thank you for reply. Since this is not a matter of file size, it is a matter of the number of queues, so unfortunately I think that it will not be solved by setting `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size` you introduced. Do you know the settings like `WindowsSize` that limits the number of queues?

Comment: Add debug on the publisher and deployer side in logback.xml paste stack trace in your question will help to find the exact issue